# p4python: perforce: file is not under permissible file system path

Tags: perforce, p4v, p4python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUbmW.png)Don't know where I have messed up. I have ran command from command prompt to change config.txt and now i can't create any new workspace because of this error. please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4ZHv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your linked image, the error message is:

```
File C:\give\null_file.txt is not inside permitted filesystem path c:/Users/agrahari
```

This indicates that your workspace definition isn't properly describing the layout of your files on your laptop.

Use P4V to edit your workspace, which is named `agrahari_agrahari-WX-1_3545`. When you do that, you will see (I believe) that the workspace `Root:` is defined as:

```
Root: c:\
```

That is telling Perforce that your Perforce-managed files can be located anywhere on your laptop in subdirectories of `c:\`.

Howwever, somehow you have set some other Perforce configuration setting, probably `P4CLIENTPATH`, to the value `c:/Users/agrahari`, indicating that Perforce-managed files can **only** be located in subdirectories of `c:/Users/agrahari`.

That's a relatively-uncommon thing to do, so I'm not certain how you did that. Perhaps you can provide more information about what configuration settings you have? For example, right-click on the `//depot/give` subfolder in your `Depot` browser tab and do "Open command prompt here" and then do:

```
p4 set
```

and update your question with the data that it shows.

If you can figure out where/why you set `P4CLIENTPATH`, you could either:

1. Remove that setting, or
2. Change `P4CLIENTPATH` to `c:\give`

Comment: Hi,yes you are right. I have set P4CLIENTPATH in p4config.txt, But I was working on multiple workspace so don't know on which workspace's config file I have made changes. Can you help me in setting it back. (I have attached command prompt response in question). I confusion - do i need to change P4CLIENTPATH to "C:\" (as showing in workspace) or "C:\give" (root folder)

Comment: I'd suggest doing `cd c:\ ` then `dir /s p4config.txt` to find all the config files. I don't see much point in setting `P4CLIENTPATH` to `c:\ `; seems just as good to remove `P4CLIENTPATH` entirely.